# C: Set custom entry point in Visual Studio Code using clang

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, clang, linker-errors

I am trying to set clang to use a function called entry() (instead of main) as the entry point (in order to prevent C-runtime initialization), but the compiler does not seem to recognize any of the entry-setting arguments -- it keeps saying that the arguments that should work are unused).
Doing -eentry makes this message appear:

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-e entry' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
```

and later:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1561 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Doing -Wl,-emymain makes this message appear:

```
At line:1 char:120
+ ...  -nostartfiles -nostdinc -nostdlib -nodefaultlibs --debug -Wl,-eentry
+                                                                  ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument
```

and later:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1561 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Doing -Xlinker -eentry makes this message appear:

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-Xlinker -eentry' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
```

and later:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1561 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Why not have a function called `entry()` and all `main()` does is call entry?

Comment: @Asadefa Not setting a custom entry point causes the compiler to call several other functions that eventually call main() (in order to set things like the C standard library up). In other words, main() isn't the true entry point.

Comment: @Asadefa I saw on your profile that you use Java for Android. There is a way to program in pure C in Android with native activity:(link is for Visual Studio but template probably usable outside of Visual Studio): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/create-an-android-native-activity-app?view=vs-2019 Note that you will have to use a graphics API (such as OpenGL or Vulkan) for rendering when using native activity.